# Python Matplotlib: plotting histogram with overlapping boundaries removed

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I am plotting a histogram using Matplotlib in Python with the `matplotlib.bar()` function.  This gives me plots that look like this:

[image]

I am trying to produce a histogram that only plots the caps of each bar and the sides that don't directly share space with the border of another bar, more like this: (I edited this using gimp)

[image]

How can I achieve this using Python?  Answers using `matplotlib` are preferable since that is what I have the most experience with but I am open to anything that works using Python.

For what it's worth, here's the relevant code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as pp

bin_edges, bin_values = np.loadtxt("datafile.dat",unpack=True)
bin_edges = np.append(bin_edges,500.0)

bin_widths = []
for j in range(len(bin_values)):
    bin_widths.append(bin_edges[j+1] - bin_edges[j])

pp.bar(bin_edges[:-1],bin_values,width=bin_widths,color="none",edgecolor='black',lw=2)


pp.savefig("name.pdf")
```

Comment: Look at the `stepfilled` type histogram, and set the facecolor to white -- http://matplotlib.org/examples/statistics/histogram_demo_histtypes.html

Comment: more fancy versions: http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/filled_step.html

Comment: My data are already binned, and I don't have access to the original, unbinned data, so I don't think I can use `pyplot.hist`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the easiest way is to use the step function instead of bar:
 http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/step_demo.html

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as pp

# Simulate data
bin_edges = np.arange(100)
bin_values = np.exp(-np.arange(100)/5.0)

# Prepare figure output
pp.figure(figsize=(7,7),edgecolor='k',facecolor='w')
pp.step(bin_edges,bin_values, where='post',color='k',lw=2)
pp.tight_layout(pad=0.25)
pp.show()
```

If your bin_edges given represent the left edge use where='post'; if they are the rightern side use where='pre'. The only issue I see is that step doesn't really plot the last (first) bin correctly if you use post (pre). But you could just add another 0 bin before/after your data to make it draw everything properly.

Example 2 - If you want to bin some data and draw a histogram you could do something like this:

```
# Simulate data
data = np.random.rand(1000)

# Prepare histogram
nBins = 100
rng = [0,1]
n,bins = np.histogram(data,nBins,rng)
x = bins[:-1] + 0.5*np.diff(bins)

# Prepare figure output
pp.figure(figsize=(7,7),edgecolor='k',facecolor='w')
pp.step(x,n,where='mid',color='k',lw=2)
pp.show()
```

Comment: Links rot and link-only answers become useless over time. Please consider adding detail and the relevant parts within the answer.